# Linux kernel programming: implicit declaration of function 'vmalloc'

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am adding system call to Linux kernel 6.22.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#incldue <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/lists.h>
#include <asm-i386/uaccess.h>

asmlinkage long sys_mypstree(char* buffer2copy){
     char* buffer = (char*)vmalloc(sizeof(buffer2copy));
     ...
}
```

Then when i make the kernel.It shows the warning:implicit declaration of function 'vmalloc'.So,what am i gonna do now?

Comment: `#include <linux/vmalloc.h>`. You really shouldn't ask these questions if you are messing with kernel..Or you shouldn't mess with kernel if you are asking such a questions. BTW, what is kernel 6.22? Are you from the future or something?

Comment: @EugeneSh.Sorry,it's 2.6.22. I am a student and is now starting learning linux kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should definitely:

`#include <linux/vmalloc.h>` as it will fix your warning.